# Next-auth no secret en producción

Tags: next.js, deployment, next

Hace unas semanas implemente next-auth con la versión de next.js 14

Al momento de desarrollar en la consola tenía advertencias de que estaba faltando un secret, esto lo solucione agregado una variable de entorno que se llame NEXTAUTH_SECRET.
En un primer deploy funcionó todo correctamente, sin embargo en un segundo deploy, al acceder al sitio, en la consola del servidor muestra el siguiente error:

> > prueba2@0.1.0 start
> > next start

▲ Next.js 14.0.3

- Local:        http://localhost:3000

✓ Ready in 3.5s
[next-auth][error][NO_SECRET]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#no_secret Please define a secret in production. i [MissingSecretError]: Please define a secret in production.
at t.assertConfig (/app/.next/server/chunks/525.js:16:16588)
at v (/app/.next/server/chunks/525.js:16:9935)
at async s (/app/.next/server/chunks/525.js:40:20616)
at async A (/app/.next/server/chunks/426.js:1:35142) {
code: 'NO_SECRET'
}
Error: There is a problem with the server configuration. Check the server logs for more information.
at s (/app/.next/server/chunks/525.js:40:20898)
at async A (/app/.next/server/chunks/426.js:1:35142)
[Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] {
digest: '2568780814'
}

Mi código es el siguiente en api/auth/providers

```
import axios from "axios";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: "credentials",
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
            },

        async authorize(credentials: any) {
            try {
                const response = await axios.post(
                    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/users/login`,
                    credentials
                );

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    const user = response.data;
                    return user;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error during API authentication:", error);
                return null;
            }
        },
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
],
callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }: any) {
        if (user) {
            return {
                ...token,
                userId: user?.id,
                email: user?.email,
                firstName: user?.firstName,
                lastName: user?.lastName,
                admin: user?.admin,
                superAdmin: user?.superAdmin,
            };
        }
        return token;
    },

    async session({ session, token, user }) {
        return {
            ...session,
            user: {
                ...session.user,
                userId: token.userId,
                email: token.email,
                firstName: token?.firstName,
                lastName: token?.lastName,
                admin: token?.admin,
                superAdmin: token?.superAdmin,
            },
        };
    },
},

session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days in seconds
},
pages: {
    signIn: "/",
},
};
```

que luego llamo en api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "../../proivider/Credendial";
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

A su vez en el package.json tengo comandos que diferencian las variables de entorno de development, staging y production. El .env sería algo así:

```
NODE_ENV= entorno (staging, development o prodution)
NEXTAUTH_URL= 
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=mi secreto
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=
```

La verdad no sé que estoy haciendo mal o si estoy obviando pasos importantes de next-auth.
Aclaro que el deploy no es en vercel